# Information about Vault.dll and Vaultcli.dll

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows

I was stumbling through the dlls in System32 when I came across the vault and vaultcli dlls. I'm assuming that these libraries work with password storage and I was wondering if anyone had any more information on these. I tried searching Google but was only able to find a bunch of those "is this a virus" and "fix this error" sites. I'm assuming these are C/C++ libraries because I tried adding references to them in a C# project with no success. I'd like to find out what methods these dlls contain and if it's possible to reference them from C# using `DllImport` and an `extern`.

Comment: `dumpbin /exports vaultcli.dll` will show what functions it exports. Looks like vault.dll is something like a COM object (only exports a `DllGetClassObject` and a `DllCanUnloadNow`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin thank you, I was completely unaware of that function. I'll have to try this and do some more research on `DllGetClassObject` and `DllCanUnloadNow`. Admittedly, my C/C++ knowledge isn't the greatest so my understanding of interaction with unmanaged code outside of user32.dll and similar libraries is also limited.

Comment: `dumpbin` is part of the Windows SDK, so if you don't have that, you may need to download/install it first.

Comment: @JerryCoffin MSDN states that it's also included with Visual C++ which  I have installed as part of the default install of VS2012. I'll run a search for it on my local machine. If I don't find it is there a specific version of the SDK I need, or will the latest work?

Comment: Yes, if you've installed VS 2012, it should be there. Just open one of the VS 2012 command windows and it *should* work. If you need an SDK, just about any version should work (it's been there for years).

Comment: @JerryCoffin It appears that 4 different versions install with VS2012, x86, x64, x86/x64, and x32 ARM (no love for Itanium I guess) so hopefully one of them will be able to work. Thanks for the information!

Comment: x86 ARM* SO won't allow me to edit that comment and I just realized that there's no such thing as x32. In my head I was writing 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaultcmd.exe (and its dependency vaultcli.dll) are the command-line equivalent to the [Credential Manager](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details) in Control Panel (In Windows7, under Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> Credential Manager.)

Starting with Windows 8 (and the Universal Windows Platform)  Windows started including [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).  This is a .Net library that is easy to use from C#.  It can add, read, and list credentials.

It seems to be a part of Windows, not the .Net framework.  To get it to work, I had to set PlatformLevel in my .csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<Reference Include="Windows.Security">
      <HintPath>$(SYSTEMROOT)\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Security.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```